# Using PHP $_COOKIE to manage session vars

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Due to server settings I am having to use $_COOKIE instead of $_SESSION to manage session vars for a project.

On my search form I set an initial cookie but am unclear whether this is helpful or needed?

```
setcookie('NOSG', 'oHai', time()+7200, '/', 'some.org');
```

Each time the search results page loads I iterate over the cookies and back date the ones I need to clear and then set the new values like so:

```
if ($board) {
  foreach ($_COOKIE as $k => $v) { 
    if (preg_match('/boa_/', $k)) {
      setcookie($k, '', time()-3600, '/', 'some.org');
    }
  }
  foreach ($people as $p) {
    setcookie('boa_'.$p->ID, $p->whatever, time()+7200, '/', 'some.org');
  }
}
```

Mostly this is used for making sticky selections in multi-line `<SELECT>` inputs.

Is this approach sound?  I have rarely used $_COOKIE for anything.

// EDIT  1:12 PM GMT-06:00
All of the comments and answers are focused on fixing sessions.  I assume this is because there is some reason the method suggested is NOT sound?  The question asked is about using $_COOKIE to remember form settings.  Would anyone care to respond as to why the method I am using is or is not appropriate to the problem?

Comment: What kind of server settings?

Comment: You really should change your server settings to allow sessions. I've never, ever seen a site that couldn't have sessions... $_COOKIE data is freely readable and editable by the user.

Comment: Permission denied.  session.save_path is set to /var/lib/php/session      PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: BTW, are you the same Pekka from Perlmonks 10 years ago?

Comment: @ceejayoz nothing stored that matters or is private.  It's only used to re-set the search forms to previous selections.  So if you had selected Agency 1,2 and 5 and Board Member 36 - 41 those would be set in the form when it reloads.

Comment: @jerrycarciuh That's an easy thing to fix. Just change session.save_path to `/tmp/something` or set the permissions on `/var/lib/php/session` so it's writeable by the webserver. Fix the root cause, don't make a clunky workaround.

Comment: @ceejayoz - what makes it clunky?  I'm unclear.

Comment: It's clunky because you're implementing something that's already native to the language. Session storage exists for a reason.

Comment: @jerry nope! I don't speak Perl at all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the respondents addressed my question:  Is using $_COOKIE to store session data a sound method?

Experience has taught me what they would not.  Not all browsers handle cookies in the same way.  For instance Internet Explorer has limits per domain on the number of cookies:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941495

So the answer is- $_SESSION is superior to cookies as it is handled by PHP in the same manner for all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

The error

```
Permission denied. session.save_path is set to /var/lib/php/session PHP Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0
```

Is due to an error on the part of your host/system administrator.  They should set the permissions on /var/lib/php/session to 777 so it is writable by all users.  If they are using something that executes your PHP script as your user, the data is still safe because your user will own the session data file so no one else can view or modify it.

Alternatively, you can change the session save path on the fly to a directory under your control.

If you were to have a common file that initiated your session, add this before session_start():

```
session_save_path('/home/yoursite/sessions');
// or
session_save_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../sessions');
// or, an alternate method
ini_set('session.save_path', '/home/yoursite/sessions');
session_start();
```

Then just created that folder and set the permissions appropriately so it is readable/writable by your user only.

Comment: Whilst my answer would work ... this is a more sensible solution so I've upvoted it. I'd still abstract away the session management into an object though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Technically all a session is, is a text file (OK, you can hold the data in a database as well) containing variables that's identified by a value held in a cookie (or the address bar).

It wouldn't be impossible to recreate the functionality within PHP using things like setcookie(), serialize() and file_put_contents() writing to a folder outside the web tree ... though you might also need a Cron job to schedule garbage collection (to be fair, PHPs native session GC doesn't seem to be spectacular).

You'd just need to create a custom session handling object and set the "session" id for it in a cookie exactly the same as if you were using normal session handling - except instead of using $_SESSION you'd use you Session::get() and Session::set() methods.

If you keep the API clean then, at a future date if you manage to get session handling enabled on the server, you'd only need to tweak your session handling object and it wouldn't affect the rest of your program code - it's probably a good idea to abstract away then session handling anyway.